# How to work with 2 full pages in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a book and would like to be able to work with 2 pages at a time (write, not just read them as in Full Screen View). How do I make Word 2007 fill the screen with two pages with the aspect ratio of paper pages (8.5" x 11"). I have a 21 diagonal screen, but am willing to move up to 27" if I can get around 75% zoom. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using *Word 2010*, but I doubt it is much different.

View the document in **Print Layout** view and adjust the zoom until two pages appear side-by-side.  Make sure you have at least two pages in your document or you won't see the second page.

It's based entirely on the zoom level and the size of the window.  My 22" screen at 1920x1080 resolution and 85% zoom can show two full Letter sized pages if I hide the ribbon (double-click **Home**.)  However, I can't force it to have the top of the current page at the top of the screen, I have to manually scroll it into position.

Comment: Cool tip - works on Word 2000 as well. To align the current page at the top of the screen, use `PgDn` to get to the page you want.